# Creating a tag from one DataFrame column according to a group from another column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multilabel-classification

The following is a simplification of my data frame:
I have thousands of gene pairs that repeat in different cell_types and 3 cell types (9 combinations possible)

| Gene pairs | cell_types | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gene4_gene5 | cell1_cell2 |  |
| gene1_gene2 | cell1_cell1 |  |
| gene1_gene2 | cell1_cell3 |  |
| gene2_gene3 | cell3_cell2 |  |
| gene4_gene5 | cell2_cell2 |  |
| gene4_gene5 | cell1_cell2 |  |

in all my genepairs that are the same (here I used groupby) I want to check if certain cell_types combinations are present. If they are, for example a group of gene pair has "cell1_cell2", "cell1-cell3" and "cell1-cell1" present, then I want to give this gene pair a label in a new column saying "cell1 is a universal sender" and one gene pair can have multiple labels. I would like to see the column added to my original df to function as metadata.
I've seen multiple questions and videos and can't code this properly. Can anyone give me a hand please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Given that you'd like to stick to your original data structure a solution could be to use df.loc to find all values in the cell_types column that match the given value in the 'Gene pairs' column, convert that to a list and check if all of the values in a predefined list of cell types that defines a "universal sender" appear in that list:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "Gene pairs": "gene4_gene5", "cell_types": "cell1_cell2" }, { "Gene pairs": "gene1_gene2", "cell_types": "cell1_cell1" }, { "Gene pairs": "gene1_gene2", "cell_types": "cell1_cell3" }, { "Gene pairs": "gene2_gene3", "cell_types": "cell3_cell2" }, { "Gene pairs": "gene4_gene5", "cell_types": "cell1_cell1" }, { "Gene pairs": "gene4_gene5", "cell_types": "cell1_cell3" } ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new column'] = df['Gene pairs'].apply(lambda x: "universal sender" if all(item in df.loc[df['Gene pairs'] == x]['cell_types'].tolist() for item in ["cell1_cell2", "cell1_cell3", "cell1_cell1"]) else None)
```

Output:

```
|    | Gene pairs   | cell_types   | new column       |
|---:|:-------------|:-------------|:-----------------|
|  0 | gene4_gene5  | cell1_cell2  | universal sender |
|  1 | gene1_gene2  | cell1_cell1  |                  |
|  2 | gene1_gene2  | cell1_cell3  |                  |
|  3 | gene2_gene3  | cell3_cell2  |                  |
|  4 | gene4_gene5  | cell1_cell1  | universal sender |
|  5 | gene4_gene5  | cell1_cell3  | universal sender |
```

Or you can wrap it in a function for better readability or if you want to add additional filters:

```
def lookup(row):
  cells = sorted(df.loc[df['Gene pairs'] == row['Gene pairs']]['cell_types'].tolist())
  if all(item in cells for item in ["cell1_cell2", "cell1_cell3", "cell1_cell1"]):
    return_value = "universal sender" 
  else:
    return_value = None
  return return_value

df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda row: lookup(row), axis=1)
```